# Detaching dynamics $scope

Tags: angularjs

Good day to all.

There is a problem. 
Create one object **$rootScope.metaContent** (need just $rootScope). In the future, to work with the data of the object, creating a new based on the first **$scope.addMeta = $rootScope.metaContent**. Needless to say, when I'm working with the second (adding an object, change its data or purify) is changed first. But I need to work with the second (**$scope.addMeta**), that would be the first not changed. It is necessary to restore the data to the source by pressing one button "Undoing". 
How can they decouple from each other???

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a deep copy of an object or an array in angular using [**angular.copy**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
$scope.addMeta = angular.copy($rootScope.metaContent);
```